# Is there a way in mongoose create global instance call for all Schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, call, instance

I know that it is possible to create instance method for each Schema, but is there a way of creating instance call that relates to all Schemas.

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: @SmitaAhinave can you please explain where to look for the answer? I've seen this before.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to create a function and then that function want to use for all schema.

If I have understood your requirement then you need to create a function in separate file and add that file as a schema plugin.

For example:

in **lastUpdate.js** file create a function that function will be use for different schema

```
module.exports = exports = function lastUpdatePlugin (schema) {
  schema.add({ updateTime: Date })

  schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.updateTime= new Date
    next()
  });
}
```

in **user.js** schema file:

```
var lastUpdate = require('./lastUpdate');//load lastUpdate.js file
var User= new Schema({name: String, ... });
User.plugin(lastUpdate);
```

in **bank.js** schema file:

```
var lastUpdate = require('./lastUpdate');//load lastUpdate.js file
var Bank= new Schema({bankName: String, ... });
Bank.plugin(lastUpdate);
```

Then when save `user` and `bank` then automatically update `updateTime` for each schema

Comment: Yeah it's good example too, thanks, but it isn't actually solves the problem, my main problem is custom filters, like call User.customWhere(...) which when called  may do User.where with RegEx for example.